# How to expose DependencyProperties within 2 ItemsSource lists (doesn't propagate)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

Got a StackPanel/ItemsSource within another StackPanel/ItemsSource. The inner one has a Value that updates.  Cannot get it to propagate an update to the UI.

Note: As a Registered DependencyProperty - it never updates. As a simple Property {get;set;} it updates ONCE then never again.   What should it or they be in order to propagate?

Already checked numerous websites, books, etc - their examples don't demonstrate this use case or work.

What is missing here (just in the propagation)?

NOTE! (if it's not clear) - This is a paired-down fully-running sample to illustrate the problem. Should be clear this isn't even close to prod, let alone int or dev.

(UPDATE: Appears to be a Windows Store app specific issue as it works in std WPF/etc)

SAMPLE DependencyProperty code (.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace TestDependency
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private TopData topData;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Do();
        }

        public async void Do() {

            topData = new TopData();
            this.TopItemsControl.ItemsSource = topData;

            var dispatcher = Dispatcher;

            var action = new Action(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                    {
                        topData[0][1].Value = topData[0][1].Value + 1;
                    });

                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                }
            });

            await Task.Run(action);      
        }
    }

    public class TopData : ObservableCollection<MiddleData>
    {
        public TopData()
        {
            this.Add(new MiddleData("ABC", new[] {"a1", "a2", "a3"}));
            this.Add(new MiddleData("DEF", new[] {"d1", "d2", "d3"}));
            this.Add(new MiddleData("GHI", new[] {"g1", "g2", "g3"}));
        }
    }

    public class MiddleData : ObservableCollection<BottomData>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public MiddleData(string name, string[] list)
        {
            this.Name = name;

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                this.Add(new BottomData(item, 0));
            }    
        }
    }

    public class BottomData : DependencyObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(double), typeof(BottomData), new PropertyMetadata(0d));

        public double Value
        {
            get { return (double)this.GetValue(ValueProperty); }
            set { base.SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
        }

        public BottomData(string name, double value)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and the SAMPLE xaml code to match:

```
    <Page
    x:Class="TestDependency.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestDependency"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid x:Name="TopGrid">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="StackItemTemplate">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="BottomStackPanel"  Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text=": "/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>

                <DataTemplate x:Key="SensorDataTemplate">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="TopStackPanel">
                        <Grid>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <StackPanel x:Name="MiddleStackPanel"  Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                                <ItemsControl x:Name="BottomItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StackItemTemplate}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                </ItemsControl>

                            </StackPanel>

                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Grid.Resources>

            <ItemsControl x:Name="TopItemsControl" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SensorDataTemplate}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: dymanoid: this was a completely paired down fully-running sample so that helpful people could try it out. This is very clearly not production code. I was sure hoping that people would appreciate the simplicity. (names like TopData, MiddleData, BottomData should have given it away)

Comment: Maybe you should tag this question as `Windows Phone`? I had trouble importing your sample code into a `WPF` application.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of highlights:

First, I'm not quite familiar with *Windows Phone* development: I imported your code into a WPF application. The declaration of `xmlns:local` as `"using:TestDependency"` gave me the first punch in the face; I had to replace it with `"clr-namespace:TestDependency"`.

Second, where you had:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="BottomItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=This}" ...
```

I changed it into:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="BottomItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding}"...
```

Note the removal of the `Path=This` bit from the binding declaration. This way, everything is working just fine for me: the view is updating sequentially with the incremental values coming from the `while` loop in the `async` task in your `Do()` method.

Give it a try, please.

Comment: thanks - I tried all the items above. This is for Windows 8.1 as well as Phone 8.1. In *this* case they are identical code. I run on "Local Machine" and in this case, it does the same thing it did before... sporadically update to 1 or not at all to 0.  For me it doesn't count upward. Can you try in your Local Machine? If it works, what is your setup - is it not Win 8.1? Thanks

Comment: @Jim: I can't say I completely follow what you mean. Here's the test project I used: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B91vNcnuPv_GUG51MkFyNjNIM0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I see the difference now - yours works, as does mine if retargeted. I'm targeting a Store App (Windows 8.1). I apologize for not specifying that as I thought this was an issue in how I was addressing it, not related to a specific target.  If you know how to get it working as a Store app - the points are yours. I'll add the keyword. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

BottomData needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and fire PropertyChanged for Value. This is a difference between WPF (which hooks up DPs more deeply) and other Xaml frameworks such as Windows.UI.Xaml and (I believe) Silverlight.

See [Property functionality provided by a dependency property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700353#functionality) in the [Dependency properties overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700353.aspx) on MSDN's Windows Dev Center:

> Wiring the binding is not the only thing that's needed for most data
>   binding scenarios. For a one-way or two-way binding to be effective,
>   the source property must support change notifications that propagate
>   to the binding system and thus the target. For custom binding sources,
>   this means that the property must support INotifyPropertyChanged.

This can be done fairly easily in the [PropertyChangedCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.propertychangedcallback.aspx) hooked up from the DependencyProperty's [PropertyMetadata](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br208774.aspx).

```
public class BottomData : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(double), typeof(BottomData), new PropertyMetadata(0d,new PropertyChangedCallback(OnValueChanged)));

    public double Value
    {
        get { return (double)this.GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public BottomData(string name, double value)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        BottomData bd = d as BottomData;
        bd.NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
    }

    void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: @Jim Note that for the binding to work, you only need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise its `PropertyChanged` event when the data has changed, You don't need to extend `DependencyObject` and make the property a `DependencyProperty`.

Comment: Thanks Rob - I implemented your recommendations. Updates occur, except in my source app to which I discovered that my updates (accelerometer) were in firehose mode and overwhelming the UI thread. Ticking that down to 100ms each made it work there too. (Just identifying that in case others have a similar issue). Thx.